# Cant quite get my JS regex to work with wildcrd

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

Iv been trying to get a JS regex to match as as follows:

"some string stuff [other string stuff] more string stuff"

The '[' and ']' characters are optional.
The text between then is not optional (and can be a single alphanumeric or even a full sentence).
So far I've come up with (and many iterations of other ideas in between):

```
/^(some string stuff \[?.*\]? more string stuff)$/gim
```

note the 'gim' arguments as I'm testing line by line, finding all matches and ignoring case.
But every test seems to frustratingly almost work but not quite, my regex fu is not all that strong it seems!
Iv trawled through other forum posts and likewise some almost work but not quite even after much tinkering.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

the "some string stuff " at the start and " more string stuff" at the end are mandatory for the string to be valid. Its just the text between them that has variance; ie could be anything so long as its not a line break.

examples of valid text:

```
some string stuff [other string stuff] more string stuff
some string stuff other string stuff more string stuff
some string stuff string more string stuff
some string stuff [string] more string stuff
```

examples of invalid text:

```
some string stuff more string stuff
some string stuff [] more string stuff
some string stuff  more string stuff
some string stuff \n more string stuff
```

Comment: It seems to work for me: https://regex101.com/r/nK1hS7/1.

Comment: There's no point in having optional characters around `.*`, since `.*` will match those characters all by itself.

Comment: Give a handful of sample input and the expected output. Your question is fairly broad/hard to interpret as it is written.

Comment: It would help if you gave examples of strings that it should **not** match. Your regexp matches anything that begins with `some string stuff` and ends with `more string stuff`.

Comment: The space after the `\]?` in your regex is a non-breaking space, not a standard space, so it doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar good point about the .* matching with the optional characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^([A-Za-z ])+([\[]?)[A-Za-z ]+([\]]?)([A-Za-z ]+)/gim
```

Comment: Please add some description about what and why is this solving.